# importing images to a drupal site

Tags: drupal, module

I used the data_export_import on my drupal site to copy over a content type 'dog' nodes from my live site to the test site. The import when ok expect for the images of the dogs. The files renamed themselves eg 5D3_019857_1366x768.jpg became filebeTgah - (not a jpg file) 
and the nodes are all showing incorrect  images. 
I did get the following error on the first import try but I exported again and re-imported and didn't get the error the second time, just the correct images are not showing. 

    `An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: /xxx/en/batch?id=472&op=do StatusText: error ResponseText: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7721 of /home/example.com/includes/common.inc).
•   Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 702643 of 835473 bytes in data_export_import_import_nodes() (line 592 of /example.com/sites/all/modules/data_export_import/includes/profiles/nodes.inc).
•   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in data_export_import_import_nodes() (line 593 of /example.com/sites/all/modules/data_export_import/includes/profiles/nodes.inc).
•   An error occurred while processing data_export_import_batch_import_dataset_lines with arguments: Array ( [0] => sites/default/files/images/data_export_import/nodes/20140119_101319_nodes_dogs.dataset [1] => Array ( [0] => field_picture [1] => field_profile_picture ) )`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reupload all my images for the nodes where the error showed. Couldn't find a better fix.